# "click" for a dynamically created link isn't getting triggered

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to add a link dynamically and attach "onclick" event on it. Here's a simplified version of what I have:

```
for (var i = 0; ....) {
    var a1 = document.createElement("a");
    a1.innerHTML = "My link123";
    a1.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      myFunc(someArray[i].property1, event);
      // alert("test123");
    });

    var p1 = document.createElement("p");
    var sp1 = document.createElement("span");
    //..........

    divContainer.innerHTML += a1.outerHTML + p1.outerHTML + sp1.outerHTML;
 }
```

But it doesn't trigger the "click" event when I click on it.

**update**:

after it's created and I click on it, I get:
`myFunc(someArray[i].property1, event); -- Cannot read property 'property1' of undefined`

I guess it's something related to how clojures are evaluated.

**update2**

I've tried this:

```
a1.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  (function(i2){
    myFunc(i2, event);
  })(myArray[i].property1);
});
```

But it said at runtime when I clicked on it "property1 isn't defined"; How can I fix that?

Comment: You should `.appendChild(a1)` if you want the click event to stay intact, rather than copying the HTML produced.

Comment: This will also be relevant: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/218196)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, actually I have other html elements created dynamically along with it, for them I'm using "outerHTML". How can I combine these 2 approaches?

Comment: @Joshimari: So what? Serializing the DOM element to HTML will loose all bound event handlers. Nothing you can do about that. *"How can I combine these 2 approaches?"* Don't. Use the DOM API to mutate the document. Call `divContainer.appendChild` for each new child.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> divContainer.innerHTML += a1.outerHTML + p1.outerHTML + sp1.outerHTML;
> ```

You are serialising the DOM nodes (both the new ones and the ones already in `divContainer`) to HTML, which doesn't include the event listeners, and then creating new DOM nodes from the HTML.

Use `appendChild` and friends instead.

```
divContainer.appendChild(a1);
divContainer.appendChild(p1);
divContainer.appendChild(sp1);
```

Comment: @Joshimari — That's a different problem. As Felix said: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/218196

Comment: @Joshimari — You're still trying to read `i` inside the click event handler. By the time the click happens, `i` will have changed. Read [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/218196) again.

Comment: You capture the value of `i` when you go around the loop instead of when you click.

Comment: I know. How should I fix it? Show me an example.

Comment: There are examples in the linked question.